# How to disable the submit button for that session once the user submits the form in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, survey

I am creating an application on Oracle Apex version 18 that takes survey from users.
I have used form on table for that purpose. However, users are able to submit the form multiple times. Is there a way to freeze the submit button once the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you have to be able to find out whether it was already submitted (for example, record in a table gets its `ID`; or, `survey_date` gets is set to `sysdate`).

Then create a condition for that button. A simple option is to use a function body that returns Boolean, e.g.

```
return :P1_ID is null;
```

which will render the button only if :P1_ID item is empty. If it is not, you won't see the button any more.

Comment: Thanks..I got your point but when I am trying using this logic, it gets permanently disabled..can you pls briefly describle what all changes I need to make? Like what server side condition I should give and what dynamic action should be used?

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance I would try setting the page attribute **Enable duplicate page submissions** to No.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't want users to be able to answer the same survey multiple times.

In order to achieve this you can use a server side condition as Littlefoot suggested, but you seem to have problems with setting up the server side condition properly.

If you use a hidden item on your page, which holds the value of the current survey the user has to answer like "P1_SURVEY_ID", you can add a server side condition that doesn't allow the user to answer it again, if he already has:

```
Type: No rows returned

SQL Query: select * from YOUR_SURVEYS where SURVEY_ID = :P1_SURVEY_ID;
```

This way the user can only click the button if he has not answered this specific survey yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a easy solution:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4167853?start=15&tstart=0

> Simply add the "Page Submit" TRUE Action to your Dynamic Action and
>   set the Show Processing "o Yes. Then you don't even need any Enable or
>   Disable Actions on your button.